# Fermi coordinates for a Friedman Robertson Walker metric

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, metric-tensor, conventions, coordinate-systems

I am trying to derive the Fermi normal coordinates formula for a FRW Universe given in  Eq. (4) of a paper by [Nicolis et al (2008)](http://arxiv.org/abs/0811.2197):
$$ds^2\approx -[1-(\dot{H}+H^2)|{\bf x}|^2]dt^2+[1-{1\over 2}H^2|{\bf x}|^2]d{\bf x}^2$$

They start with a FRW metric:
$$
ds^2=-d\tau^2+a^2(\tau)d{\bf y}^2
$$
and perform the coordinate change
$$
\tau=t-{1\over 2}H|{\bf x}|^2, \quad {\bf y}={{\bf x}\over a} [1+{1\over 4}H^2|{\bf x}|^2],
$$
 To derive their Eq. (4), I use the metric transformation formula given in Eq. (5.69) of Dodelson's [Modern Cosmology](http://books.google.co.nz/books?id=iBc9TmNLD7kC&lpg=PA132&vq=gauge&pg=PA133#v=onepage&q&f=false):
$$
\tilde{g}_{\alpha\beta}(\tilde{x}){\partial \tilde{x}^\alpha \over \partial x^\mu}{\partial \tilde{x}^\beta \over \partial x^\nu}=g_{\mu\nu}(x).
$$
I take the tilde coordinates as the FRW ones. So for $\mu=\nu=1$, I have:
$$
\frac{1}{16} |{\bf x}|^2 \left(9 (x^1)^2+(x^2)^2+(x^3)^2\right) H^4+\frac{1}{2} |{\bf x}|^2 H^2+1=g_{1,1}
$$
I then take the limit that $|\vec{x}| H\ll 1$ to get 
$$
g_{11}\approx1 + {1\over 2} H^2 |{\bf x}|^2
$$
which differs from their result by a minus sign. Any help in explaining this discrepancy would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:** I was able to get their result using the Mathematica package [TensoriaCalc](http://www.stargazing.net/yizen/Tensoria.html) which has a coordinate change command. This confirms Nicolis et al are correct and I am doing something wrong in my calculation.

Comment: @igael I don't think I ever have $g_{11}\approx 1-{1\over 2}H^2x_1^2$.

Comment: @Virgo: I was wrong, sorry. With $z =\frac{x_1^2 H^2}{2} , p=|\vec{x}|^2 H^2$ , I get $g_{11} = \frac{p^2}{16}+\frac{p z}{2}+\frac{p}{2}+z^2+1 \approx 1+\frac {p}{2}+(z^2+\frac {p z}{2})$ instead of $\approx 1+\frac{p}{2}$ or $\approx 1-\frac{p}{2}$. If it's not too boring for you, could you please expand your approximation ?

Comment: @Virgo : mathjax doesn't render the same in comments ... without mathjax : g11= p²/16  + pz/2 + p/2 + z² + 1 ( followed by correct renderring )

Comment: @igael I think you can drop the $z^2$ and $pz$ term as we are assuming $xH\ll1$

Comment: formally, it is p which is very small. In p²/16 + pz/2 + p/2 + z², p² is very small, pz too and z² , I don't know ( I don't know the implicit formalism with links $x_1$ to $|\vec{x}$ ). Sorry and thanks

Comment: Just looking at these expressions, one notice a dot above $H$ in the first expression. I assume the notation means the time derivative of $H$, which therefore assumes $H$ has a time dependence. From the 4th expression one can also see where this $H$-dot would come from for the $g_{11}$ component. This $H$-dot seems to be missing from the 6th expression.

Comment: @flippiefanus I am trying to derive the second term on the RHS of the first expression, not the first term on the RHS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a small subtlety. As stated by the authors in the paper, in the given transformation law $a$ and $H$ are evaluated at $t$ rather than at $\tau$. Thus the formula you get is almost right but $a(\tau)$ and $a(t)$ don't cancel, so actually
$$g_{11} = \left(\frac{a(\tau)}{a(t)}\right)^2\left(1+\frac{1}{2}H^2|\mathbf x|^2\right)$$
Then using the transformation law above,
$$a(\tau)=a\left(t-\frac{1}{2}H|\mathbf x|^2\right)\approx a(t)-\frac{1}{2}H|\mathbf x|^2 \dot a(t)$$
Therefore
$$g_{11} = \left(1-\frac{1}{2}H^2|\mathbf x|^2 \right)^2\left(1+\frac{1}{2}H^2|\mathbf x|^2\right)\approx 1-\frac{1}{2}H^2|\mathbf x|^2$$